# Filemaker Pro 12 insert field Contents into applescript?

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I have a record in filemaker pro 12 that contains some basic information about users computers on the local network. One of the fields, is a IP Address field. I would like to take the contents of this field and insert it into a short applescript that will run when a button is clicked on.

```
tell application "Screen Sharing"
    getURL "MacForm::IP Address"
end tell
```

MacForm is the name of my form and IP Address is the name of my field. how do I insert the contents of this field into the apple script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use calculated AppleScript =

```
"tell application \"Screen Sharing\"¶    
getURL " & Quote ( MacForm::IP Address ) & "¶
end tell"
```

[image]

Comment: keep getting an error A"(" can't go after this property

Comment: When it runs it is putting the string "MacForm::IP Address" into the Screen Sharing application instead of the actual IP Address "192.168.1.135"

Comment: Are you sure you're doing this correctly (see the screenshot)? If you are, and the MacForm::IP Address field of the current record contains `192.168.1.135`, then the calculation will return:  
`tell application "Screen Sharing"¬ getURL "192.168.1.135"¬ end tell`. Whether that's a valid AppleScript, I can't tell.

Comment: i wrote is exactly like yours and have rechecked it according to your picture and am still getting an error.

Comment: oh goodness i feel so silly, I forgot to click out of the field so it hadn't saved it self yet. Thank you so much for your help and taking the time to post a picture. it was very helpfull